# Close encounters of the third kind

Tags: sound

anyone knows how to generate the 5 tone notes of the movie?

It's only for have fun.

Thanks

Comment: Mind posting a link to some recording we can work from?

Comment: You can try `SoundNote`.

Comment: `SoundNote /@ {"G", "A", "F", "F3", "C"} // Sound`

Answer (score 7):

Using info from here: [Wikipedia Piano key frequencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_key_frequencies)

```
f[n_] := 2^((n - 49)/12) 440.

g4 = f[47];
a4 = f[49];
f4 = f[45];
f3 = f[33];
c4 = f[40]; (* Middle C *)

Sound[Play[Sin[# 2 Pi t], {t, 0, 0.7}] & /@ {g4, a4, f4, f3, c4}]
```

[image: Close Encounters sound]

For interest, the keys above are plotted in red in the chart below.  The black lines are octaves on the key of C, i.e. every 12th key: 28, 40, 52, 64.  The frequency doubles every octave.  The perfect fifth below C5 (52) is G4 (47), whose frequency (shown in green) is almost mid-way between the frequencies of the surrounding octave C4 to C5.

```
Show[Plot[{f[n], f[28], f[40], f[47], f[52], f[64]}, {n, 20, 70}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Gray, Gray, Gray, Green, Gray, Gray}],
 Graphics[{
   Line[{{28, 0}, {28, f[28]}}],
   {Thick, Line[{{40, 0}, {40, f[40]}}]},
   {Red, Line[{{47, 0}, {47, f[47]}}]},
   {Red, Line[{{49, 0}, {49, f[49]}}]},
   {Red, Line[{{45, 0}, {45, f[45]}}]},
   {Red, Line[{{33, 0}, {33, f[33]}}]},
   {Red, Dotted, Thick, Line[{{40, 0}, {40, f[40]}}]},
   Line[{{52, 0}, {52, f[52]}}],
   Line[{{64, 0}, {64, f[64]}}]}], AspectRatio -> 1,
 AxesLabel -> {"key", "frequency (Hz)"}]
```

[image]

As stated here: [Wikipedia Perfect fifth Pitch ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_fifth#Pitch_ratio)

> The justly tuned pitch ratio of a perfect fifth is 3:2 (also known, in
>   early music theory, as a hemiola), meaning that the upper note makes
>   three vibrations in the same amount of time that the lower note makes
>   two.

```
Plot[{Sin[c4 2 Pi t], Sin[g4 2 Pi t]}, {t, 0, 3/g4}]
```

[image]

However, this is not quite true using the piano key frequencies, as can be seen by comparing the wavelengths.

```
s = QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert@Quantity["SpeedOfSound"];

λc4 = s/c4  (* 1.3118 m *)
λg4 = s/g4  (* 0.87552 m *)

2 λc4  (* 2.6236 m *)
3 λg4  (* 2.62656 m *)

3 λg4 - 2 λc4  (* 2.96438 mm *)
```

> Keyboard instruments such as the piano normally use an equal-tempered
>   version of the perfect fifth, enabling the instrument to play in all
>   keys. In 12-tone equal temperament, the frequencies of the tempered
>   perfect fifth are in the ratio 2^(7/12) or approximately 1.498307. An
>   equally tempered perfect fifth, defined as 700 cents, is about two
>   cents narrower than a just perfect fifth, which is approximately
>   701.955 cents.

So an alternative answer using perfect pitch will be forthcoming.  I think visiting aliens might notice the difference.

Also on this topic is, [Wikipedia Pythagorean comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_comma)

> The Pythagorean comma can be defined as ... the difference
>   between twelve just perfect fifths and seven octaves.

Comment: Hey Chris, I added a link to the sound; hope you don't mind.

Comment: after checking the movie, the real notes seem to be: A#5 c6  g#5 g#4 d#5 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZj7gUIO-2k